# Styling CSS with more than one class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style a css class in a class attribute with multiple class name, like this:

```
<div class='step active'><a href=''>Link 1</a>
<div class='step'><a href=''>Link 2</a>
<div class='step'><a href=''>Link 3</a>
```

And I try to make css code to style the active step class. This is the css code:

```
.step {
   background: #cccccc;
}
.step .active {
   background: #08a0f2;
}
```

But the code doesn't change the background color like I want. I already tried this.

```
.step > .active {
   background: #08a0f2;
}
```

But, it also doesn't work as well. How can I make it work?

Comment: Both of which you are trying selects the child element having `class` of `.active` nested under element having `class` of `.step` for the first selector, and second searches for an element which is direct child to element having `class` of `.step`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this:

```
.step.active {
   background: #08a0f2;
}
```

to learn more about css selectors read this topic:

Doc:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Usage and examples:

http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors

Comment: Yes. `.step .active` means, "a .active element which is a descendant of a .step element," aand `.step > .active` means, "a .active element which is directly a child of a .step element." `.step.active` means, "an element which is both .step and .active."

Comment: Better share a link to the docs, or MDN rather than providing a link to a blog... :)

Comment: Maybe you mixed up the doc and examples links? :-)

Comment: @Abaij you welcome CSS is a big world, but it's easy and fun.. have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, don't have a space between the names `step` and `active`. The space acts as a separator. Instead, concatenate with a `.` inbetween them:

```
.step.active {
    background: #08a0f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just write

```
.active {
 background: #08a0f2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9CNX5/